# Rollup Error:' Could not resolve' error for .js and .jsx file references inside index.ts

Tags: webpack, babeljs, rollupjs

I am trying to rollup and publish a repo with an older version of react that is using plain .js and .jsx files. It has a few typescript files as well. I have followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/alexeagleson/template-react-component-library) but added a js file and jsx file to the app and reference them index.ts in the src folder. (I added @rollup/plugin-babel to the rollup config to process the jsx file as well.) Here is my index.ts:

```
export * from './components';

// The below line gives an "Could not resolve" error when you run `npm run rollup`
export * from './path-to/my/jsfile.js';

// If you comment out the above line you get a similar error but for this jsx file.
export * from './path-to/my/jsxfile.jsx';
```

When I try to execute the `rollup -c` command I get an error that says

```
dist/esm/types/index.d.ts → dist/index.d.ts...
[!] Error: Could not resolve './path-to/my/jsfile.js' from dist/esm/types/index.d.ts
```

When I comment out the jsfile.js export line I get the error:

```
dist/esm/types/index.d.ts → dist/index.d.ts...
[!] Error: Could not resolve './path-to/my/jsxfile.jsx' from dist/esm/types/index.d.ts
```

Here is my rollup config:

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel';

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve({extensions: ['.js', '.ts']}),
      babel({ babelHelpers: 'bundled', extensions: [".js", ".jsx"], }),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      postcss(),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: [/\.(css|less|scss)$/],
  },
];
```

How can I rollup js and jsx files along with ts files?